# How to use use Python to import (.tex file), create a new (.tex file) and append the new (.tex file) from the imported (.tex file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, compilation

I have several (1000+) `.tex` files which goes something like this:

File1.tex:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Question1:

$f(x)=sin(x)$\\

Question2:

$f(x)=tan(x)$

\end{document}
```

File2.tex is similar in structure:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Question1:

$f(x)=cos(x)$\\


Question2:

$f(x)=sec(x)$\\

Question3:

$f(x)=cot(x)$

\end{document}
```

What I would like to do is write a Python script that allows me to select question 1 from `file1.tex` and question 3 from `file2.tex` and compile a new `file3.tex` file (or PDF) with the following format:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Question1:
$f(x)=sin(x)$\\

Question2:
$f(x)=cot(x)$

\end{document}
```

PS- I don't mind if I can carry out this type of work on LaTex. I just thought with Python I can eventually create a GUI.

So far I've managed to read/append a `.tex` file by manually typing what I want rather than creating some sort of a system that allows me to "copy" specific section of a .tex file or files into another another .tex file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used exactly what you had for file1 and file2.tex. I left comments throughout rather than explain step by step.

## PreProcess

The preprocess involves creating an xlsx file which will have all of the names of the tex file in the first column.

```
import os
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Filenames.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("FileNames")
worksheet.write(0, 0, "NameCol")

path = os.getcwd()  # get path to directory
filecount = 1
for file in os.listdir(path):  # for loop over files in directory
    if file.split('.')[-1] == 'tex':  # only open latex files
        worksheet.write(filecount, 0, file)
        filecount += 1

workbook.close()
```

## Select Problems

Now you go through an list to the right like I have what problems you want out of the file. 
[image: Filenames.xlsx]

## PostProcess

Now we can run through our xlsx file and create a new latex file from it.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import os

# get data
allfileqs = []
df = pd.read_excel('Filenames.xlsx')
for row in df.iterrows():
    tempqs = []
    for i in range(len(row[1].values) - 1):
        if math.isnan(row[1].values[i + 1]):
            continue
        else:
            tempqs.append(int(row[1].values[i + 1]))
    allfileqs.append(tempqs)
print(allfileqs)
allfileqs = [["Question" + str(allfileqs[i][j]) + ':' for j in range(len(allfileqs[i]))] for i in range(len(allfileqs))]

starttex = [r'\documentclass[15pt]{article}', r'\begin{document}']
endtex = [r'\end{document}']
alloflines = []


path = os.getcwd()  # get path to directory
for file in os.listdir(path):  # for loop over files in directory
    if file.split('.')[-1] == 'tex':  # only open latex files
        lf = open(file, 'r')
        lines = lf.readlines()
        # remove all new lines, each item is on new line we know
        filt_lines = [lines[i].replace('\n', '') for i in range(len(lines)) if lines[i] != '\n']
        alloflines.append(filt_lines)  # save data for later
        lf.close()  # close file
# good now we have filtered lines
newfile = []
questcount = 1
for i in range(len(alloflines)):
    for j in range(len(alloflines[i])):
        if alloflines[i][j] in allfileqs[i]:
            newfile.append("Question" + str(questcount) + ":")
            newfile.append(alloflines[i][j + 1])
            questcount += 1
# okay cool we have beg, middle (newfile) and end of tex
newest = open('file3.tex', 'w')  # open as write only
starter = '\n\n'.join(starttex) + '\n' + '\n\n'.join(newfile) + '\n\n' + endtex[0]
for i in range(len(starter)):
    newest.write(starter[i])
newest.close()
```

Comment: You sir are a genius! I see what you did now.

My next question (which you probably already know is), what if i had 1000 of files in the same format as file1, file 2 etc.

Would I need to add to this list?
'file1qs = ['Question1:', 'Question2:']
file2qs = ['Question2:']
file3qs = ['Question x:', 'Question y:']'

@GeneralCode

Comment: For these 1000 files, are you going through and deciding which problems you want, or are you going to decide up front "I would like to have question 2 from every file"? The answer to this question decides how I would go about pulling the data I want.

Comment: I want to go through the data and decide which questions I want.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer with how I would go about this project. Let me know if there's any questions. Ps. "PostProcess" has been updated from what it was before, it now reads `xlsx` rather than inserting in lists of questions.

Comment: Thank you for your input @GeneralCode, I appreciate the time and effort.
Now I just need to go over and read/understand the mechanics of it.

Comment: StackOverFlow is a great place for modern intellectuals to share ideas. I recommend `PyCharm` for debugging Python and understanding what all is happening to the data.